# How can I get AppEngine to log info level only for my app?

Tags: google-app-engine

So I've tried configuring AppEngine logging according to [this guide](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/configure-logging-in-google-app-engine/), ensuring I've configured the logging.properties file to be used in web.xml. I've configured logging.properties the following way:

```
.level = WARNING
nilsnett.chinese.backend.level = INFO
```

The package name of my logging wrapper is `nilsnett.chinese.backend`. The problem is that even with this configuration, info-level log output from my app is filtered. Evidence:

[image]

I've also tried the following config, which yielded the same result (including the logger class name at the end of the package name):

```
.level = WARNING
nilsnett.chinese.backend.JavaUtilLogger.level = INFO
```

To demonstrate that the logging.properties-file is actually read, and that I actually do write info-level logging data to app-engine in this service call, let me show you what happens when I set`.level=INFO`:

[image]

So my desired result is to have INFO and higher-level log outputs from *my packages*, while other packages, like `org.datanucleus`, only shows output if WARNING or more severe. In the example above, I want only the two lines marked with the purple star. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: have you tried to add a logger: **org.level = WARNING** ?

Comment: I tried now: Same result as the image with the purple stars. Note: I still have .level=INFO on the line above in the config.

Comment: you have INFO ? but in your question you wrote you set it to WARNING ?

Comment: I wrote that I set it to ".level=INFO" in the third example (the one with the stars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your config to:

```
.level = WARNING

# Set the default logging level for the datanucleus loggers
DataNucleus.JDO.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Persistence.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Cache.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.MetaData.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.General.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Utility.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Transaction.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Datastore.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.ClassLoading.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Plugin.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.ValueGeneration.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Enhancer.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.SchemaTool.level=WARNING

# FinalizableReferenceQueue tries to spin up a thread and fails.  This
# is inconsequential, so don't scare the user.
com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue.level=WARNING
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue.level=WARNING
```

this is are coming from logging config template, so to set datanucleus to warning you have todo like in this template.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Logging

and then just add your own logging config:

```
nilsnett.chinese.backend.level = INFO
```

this should solve it